# Simple cipher and I/O

Tags: java, encryption, io

This code is supposed to read one character from the source file; convert to the ASCII int value; add 1; convert back to a character; write to destination file.

Nothing is showing up in my destination file.

Right now, I'm not worried about getting an ASCII value greater than 255 or efficiency.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadAFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File myFile = new File("source.txt");

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            int character;

            int shift = 1;

            while ((character = reader.read()) != -1) {

                character = (int) reader.read() + shift;

                WriteAFile(Character.toString((char) character));


            }

            reader.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void WriteAFile(String line) {

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("destination.txt");

            writer.write(line);

            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the file for each character. This is both inefficient and not giving you what you want. Keep the `FileWriter` open for the duration of the program and close it in a `finally` block.

If you **must** write each character, use the [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) flag to tell the writer not to overwrite the file.

Answer (score 1):

Just to put into code form what [@Deepak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830964/deepak-bala) was saying:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
     try 
     {
        File myFile = new File("c:\\temp\\source.txt"));
        File outputFile = new File("c:\\temp\\output.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        try
        {
            int character;
            int shift = 1;

            while ((character = reader.read()) != -1) 
            {
                character = (int) reader.read() + shift;
                writer.write(Character.toString((char) character));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also make sure to specify your output path.

Comment: Hey, thanks. As a beginner, this line is kind of scary.

 File myFile = new File(Answer28522397.class.getClassLoader().getResource("source.txt").getFile());

Where did you get Answer28522397 from?

Comment: Sorry, that is my class name in the project.  It is just how I load resources when I am answering these.  Will edit that to just load "C:\temp\source.txt"